# Possibility to stop opening Google Map app while clicking the logo

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am using Google Map in an iOS app built for a client. I know that the logo at the bottom cannot and shouldn't be removed at any time. I am wondering whether I can disable the click action and stop the app jumping or not, since the client don't want the app to open an external app.

Comment: I believe we can't.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?